# What is a <dbname> in Mongo_url to connect meteor app

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

so sorry for my ignorant question, but im really new to meteor, and still tryina figure everything out. so I want to connect my app to galaxy hosting, and to do that I got a Mongo_url. But the thing is I dont know what a dbname is, I understand it is a database name, but I dont know what to repalce it with in my app. Im using atlas for the mongodb, so I tried to put it in like that but it didnt work. so just tried to put it in the way it was, and it didnt work. so i replaced it with “meteor” like this:

```
mongodb+srv://abidmir:<password>@cluster0.6fk1x.mongodb.net/Meteor(<dbname>, did not accually put this, just left the meteor part)?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

but it didnt work, and I figured it was probably because I didnt put in the proper thing. I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

The URI that Atlas gives you is supposed to have the database name in it, that is the database name you need to use.

Comment: in the link I got, it just said <dbname> and said that just put the data base name here. were can i  find the database name?

Comment: If you haven't created a database in Atlas I'm guessing you can put in any database name you want.

Comment: how do you create a database in atlas, and is it free?